# Can I create a thumbnail from a PDF file with Filestack?

Tags: pdf, upload, thumbnails

I am using Filestack to manage image files on a project I am working on. Can I create a thumbnail using Filestack's API, and how do I do it?

Comment: did you find how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy. You can use their file conversions api for this, check https://www.filestack.com/docs/api/processing/

There are a lot of options, you can choose which page(s), output format, etc.

So for example if you uploaded a pdf to filestack with handle **abcd1234** you can get a quick jpg thumbnail by using https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/output=format:jpg/abcd1234